# how to show image in table cell through json parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourimage"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
```

This code i used to get the image but how to show it in table cell.

Comment: I am using Json framework to parse it.

Comment: it's Good As You get That Parsed Content Just need To a Hold That URL data In Some DataSource (NSArray or NSMutableArray)and Try To download Images Form THese URL for this Can use The LazyDownloading Example provided By Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
[[cell imageView] setImage:img];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: 1 more question to you..in url i am passing the url of the image but i want to get image from json.such as in json response, image="http://123.jpg".i just write image in place of url.how i can do this..please help ...i'm possible..

Comment: arrayListG addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"title"]];As i m icluding this in my pgm i am getting title(extracted from json response in my table).the same way i want to get image bcoz putting url directly is as hard coding..please help..

Comment: just like add as ur title , add image url like `[imageArray addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"image url key"]];` and retrieve from the image array

Comment: try like `NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];` `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];`

Comment: sorry I'M Possible...ur earlier code works..last help i need..i want all them to show in the same cell.Image,title & source in the same cell.how can i do this,rt nw i getting all these bt in different cells.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [arrayListG objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];          cell.detailTextLabel = [source_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

Comment: please check my code..this is in connectionDidFinishLoading method:-for (int k=0; k<[_arrData count]; k++) { [arrayListG addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"title"]];
[arrayListG addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"source"]];[arrayListG addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"picture"]];       NSLog(@"===%@",arrayListG);}if ([arrayListG count]>0) {
        [tableViewG reloadData];}

Comment: this is in cellforrowatindexpath:cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0];cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:202.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:15.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayListG objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];[[cell imageView] setImage:img];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arrayListG objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];What to be changed here..please help..

Comment: please check these codes and let me know wat to change here..to get image,source and image in the same cell.

Comment: for (int k=0; k<[_arrData count]; k++) { [arrayListGTitle addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"title"]]; [arrayListGSource addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"source"]];[arrayListGPicture addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:k]valueForKey:@"picture"]]; NSLog(@"===%@",arrayListG);}if ([arrayListG count]>0) { [tableViewG reloadData];}

Comment: this is in cellforrowatindexpath:cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0];cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:202.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:15.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayListGImage objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];[[cell imageView] setImage:img]; cell.textLabel.text=[arrayListGTitle objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arrayListGSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];   do like that....

Comment: Hi!! I'M POSSIBLE,can you tell me how to get the images of same size in table cell?? Bcoz frm ur code i m getting images bt all are coming of different size..

Comment: please help me here.I have seen in android if userid is a variable then we use it like http://abc.com/user/"+userid+"/bookmarks to get web services of url. how it can be done in iPhone to achieve the same thing.I have tried the above method as well as this http://abc.com/user/userid/bookmarks.bt not getting the anything.so,can tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

FirstLy You need To parse That JSON file In Your iOS Application.
I guess You get Some URL from That JSON for The Image So You need To Download Image Form That Prased URL and Can set That IMage Over ANy UIIMageView and you can set That UIIMageView to The Content View Of `UITablViewCell`.

Here You Need To Just Manage One THing Suppose You have Many Images To be Downlaod Form The Particular path.So You should Take Care of The UI Interaction also
Here Is Good Example Of How TO download Images form The URL and set That DownLoaded Image Over The UIImageView and set That UIImageView on to the ContentView of `UITableViewcell`.In this Example you'll also see The Way of How Can you Add The These Images Over The TableViewcEll.

[Here Is The Link For That Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html)

I hope It may help You.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[[cell imageView] setImage:img];
```

But thats probably not going to run very well because you're downloading the images synchronously and that will most likely make your app stutter.

You should use lazy loading for the images, for an example take a look at
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[aTweet objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```